# Automatically inserting version numbers in Aptana Studio

Tags: javascript, git, aptana, aptana3

Lets say I have some comments at the top of my javascript/php/html etc and I want to add in automated version numbers in Aptana Studio... how could I do this. 
All of my projects use git in Aptana and I really just want the git version number for the file to be inserted?

In other dev apps I can do something like `$VERSION` in the file but I cant find a reference for this in Aptana.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a filter driver in order to replace the `$VERSION` by the current version number deduced from a git describe:

- see "[Is it possible to add a version number using git / github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921307/6309)" for more on `git describe`
- see "[how to add revision and build date to source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2698081/6309)" for an example of content filter driver

However, there are other ways to put that information, as discussed in "[Enable ident string for Git repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792838/enable-ident-string-for-git-repos/1796675#1796675)":

> Recommended way of embedding version info in product is to use build system for that; see below for details and alternate approaches.

Comment: that's kinda genius... I was hoping for something simple like in TextMate but I'm going to give your suggestion a try...