# Automatically add revision number to git in comments on github

Tags: git, github, autocommenting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add a version number using git / github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920548/is-it-possible-to-add-a-version-number-using-git-github)

I host a git repository on github.

Is it possible to add the revision to the comments at the start of my script, so every time I commit a new version, this number is counted up?

Also the date of the last commit would be great, if it is shown in comments.

Comment: this is not a duplicate of that at all!

Comment: I would like to have the version number (or tag) directly in my source-code without having to edit it each time I commit a change